# Fonts lineHeight equalization in UITextView

Tags: ios, objective-c, fonts, uitextview, core-text

I have a UITextView set with some text with both chinese and latin characters.

[image]

As you can see, the lineSpace is different depending if there is a latin character or not in the line above. Obviously, **I need to remove this difference and to equalize the lineSpace**.
Here are the statements :

- I work with an AttributedString
- The font is different depending if the character is latin or chinese
- The point above needs to stay true
- The lineHeight is different between the 2 fonts

I almost sure than the reason of my problem comes from this last point but since the lineHeight of the font is not editable, I'm a bit stuck.

I already try to play with those properties

```
style.minimumLineHeight = mylineSpacing;
style.maximumLineHeight = mylineSpacing;
style.lineHeightMultiple = mylineSpacing;
style.lineSpacing = 0;

NSDictionary *attributes = @{
                             NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : style
                             };
```

It doesn't work. I'm thinking about using CoreText or even CoreGraphic to redraw all the characters one by one but maybe there is an easier solution. And if not, which Kit should I use ?

PS : I'm not chinese and I used random chinese text for this screenshot and I apologize to an eventual chinese stackoverflow user if my text looks stupid / no sense / or offending in any way.